# undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Might appear a Duplicate Question, but cant seem to find my way around solving this.

I'm trying to get all `Payments` for `Orders` belonging to a `Customer`.

I've got this

```
# customer.rb
has_many :orders, dependent: :restrict_with_exception, class_name: "Shoppe::Order"

# order.rb
belongs_to :customer, class_name: 'Shoppe::Customer'

# payment.rb
belongs_to :order, class_name: 'Shoppe::Order'

# payment_controller.rb
def index
@payments ||= []
@customer_orders  = @customer.orders.ordered.load
  @customer_orders.each do |d|
  @payments << d.payments
  end
end
```

in a view...

```
for payment in @payments
      tr
        td
          =  payment.id
```

I get an Error -

```
undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy   []>
```

Any help in resolving this is highly appreciated

Comment: little more error backtrace please; we need to know which part of your code is culprit; do not hesitate to paste the BT

Comment: @illusionist - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a8c7c0ae045da4527940531264ed2259. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, you are inserting the `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` objects (which is a `collection` of `Payment` instances) into the array.

Meaning: Now your array is a `multi-dimentional` array. So, now when you are looping, the iterator is getting you `collection` instead of individual `payment` objects.

Solution:
You need to `flatten` the collection

```
# payment_controller.rb
def index
@payments ||= []
@customer_orders  = @customer.orders.ordered.load
  @customer_orders.each do |d|
  @payments << d.payments
  end
end

@payments = @payments.flatten
```

Now every item should respond to `id` method

To know more about `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` see 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, doing that makes the '@payments' array empty

Comment: It means there is no any payments associated to the `orders`

Comment: I'm quite sure there is, if i remove the flatten, same error pops up for same record.